# Como devuelvo mensajes de error en una petición ajax con Alpine.js?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de facturas. Tengo un formulario de registro para las facturas el cual está hecho con alpine.js, y estoy enviando su petición a un controlador en Laravel encargado de hacer el almacenamiento de los datos. Pero éste almacenamiento depende de dos condiciones. Si la factura no está a nombre del usuario dueño de la sesión iniciada, la factura no se podrá guardar. De la misma forma, si la factura ya se guardó en la base de datos, no se podrá guardar de nuevo (porque ya se guardó antes)..
El formulario de registro me está funcionando perfectamente según las condiciones que le establecí. El problema es con los mensajes de error en caso de que no se guarde la factura, es decir, para avisarle al usuario (mediante simples mensajes en propiedades del modelo de Alpine.js) POR QUÉ la factura no se guardó.
Le coloqué dos condicionales en el controlador. Pero en el javascript no se como hacer para que al momento de intentar guardar una factura, el sistema le indique al usuario la razón por la que no se guardó.

No sé si me estoy dando a entender, pero el formulario guarda la información correctamente cuando quiero guardarla, y cuando no quiero guardarla evalúa si la factura está a nombre del dueño de la sesión iniciada. Si es así, evaluará otra condición. Si no es así, entonces la factura no se guardará. Y en ese caso debería mostrar en el HTML el mensaje "Esta factura pertenece a otro usuario, por lo tanto no se puede guardar".
Les dejaré mi controlador y mi js para que me entiendan mejor. Gracias!
[image: JS y Controlador]

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una forma de solucionarlo y quiero comentarla por si a alguien más le es de utilidad.
En mi controlador creé variables inicializadas en 0, las cuales se igualan a 1 en caso de cumplir las respectivas condicionales.
Al final de la función de mi controlador envié un array con los valores de las variables a mi javascript, utilizando la función json_encode, de manera de poder recibirlo con formato JSON en mi javascript.
Y una vez ahí, accedí a estos objetos normalmente para poder asignarlos a las propiedades correspondientes.
Igual dejaré mi código para que lo puedan ver.
Quizás no sea la solución más elegante pero es una opción.[image: envío de mensajes de error a JS]